# Messages Patterns - RabbitMQ/NestJS

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs, node-amqplib

I'm trying to integrate to a project done using NestJS, a simple api where you can publish messages with a name (or pattern) and send it to that system that has implemented a handler that matches the name.

The system I'm building is really small, it wouldn't make much of a sense using NestJS for that.

The problem I'm having is the following:

I'm creating a simple api that triggers the publish of the message onto a queue.
The consumer is on a system using NestJS.

I can't figure out how to give that messages a pattern that is recognized by that system.
For example:

Let's say I want to publish a message that has a name of "CreateRecord" with a payload to be processed from the other system that has a handler with the same name with an implementation.

Using amqplib how do I give messages a name or pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can provide a pattern in the content object when you are publishing a message.

```
publish(
  'my_exchange',
  'routing_key',
  { pattern: 'CreateRecord', data: 'Record' },
);
```